# Is it right to say "phone was rang"?

Tags: past-tense, passive-voice, past-participles

Recently I saw these two sentences in two different books

1. **So after dinner my cell phone was rang and it was Tom.** (The Journey of Andrea: Make Sure You Live Your Life to the Fullest Before ...,By Andrea)
2. **Ash was already in bed sleeping and didn't even move when the phone was rang.** (Too Fat to Dance, By David Luck, page 155, last paragraph)

Now, is it right to say "the phone was rang."?

Comment: ring, rang, rung. The phone rang. It ain't right but "literature" ain't about right and wrong. But it only works if the unschooled character is the narrator.

Comment: @Lambie - the phone was rang, that is the phone was made to ring.

Comment: @user240918 The phone ***was rung*** by the technician to test it. Not "was rang" in any case. ring, rang, rung: The church bells were rung by the priest. And in the OP's question, it can only be considered rural, regional or unschooled.

Comment: If the *phone was rang*, one might well ask *whodunnit*. :P

Answer (score 4):

Today, *was rang* is considered a non-standard form since the accepted past participle of *ring* is *rung*.  In earlier centuries, however, this was not always the case:

> June 5, [*was rang*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=nyp.33433066598511;view=1up;seq=186;skin=mobile) at the pariſh church of St. Leonard, Shoreditch, a compleat peal of caters, on Sted­man's principle, being the ſecond production in that critical method. The peal conſiſted of 5184 changes, and was performed in three hours and 47 minutes, by the ſociety of Cumberland Youths. — *The Sporting Magazine*, June 1796, 162.
>
> The lady rang the bell to enquire the cause of it, but no answer. The bell [*was rang*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=njp.32101063704595;view=2up;seq=54;skin=mobile) again, but there was no answer. — Rev. G. Owen, *Counsels to Domesticks*, Baltimore, 1844, 47.

With the rapid expansion of compulsory education in the mid-19th century and the grammar books that accompanied it, *rang* as a participle, along with other now non-standard forms, was drilled out of American youth, as in this sentence a student was to correct:

> I begun to study early, studied hard till the bell [*was rang*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc1.a0006400121;view=2up;seq=52;skin=mobile), then I run all the way and come to school in season, and recited awl my lessons perfect. — Report of the annual examination of the public schools, Boston, 1852.

Before this standardization, there was a good bit of variation in strong verbs with the umlaut paradigm *i, a, u*. Thus Shakespeare:

> … or I will scarce think you [*have swam*](https://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/views/plays/play_view.php?WorkID=asyoulikeit&Act=4&Scene=1&Scope=scene) in a gondola. — *As You Like It*, 4.1.

A number of these forms survived more readily in Scotland and the North:

> But our humbler home is yet a while on the earth, and of the earth in humbler strain it is that we would speak—though had Heaven made us a poet, we [*had sang*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc1.32106019922696;view=1up;seq=727;skin=mobile) to Tellus many a lofty hymn. — *Blackwood’s Edinburgh Magazine* 37/234 (April 1835).
>
> The love which [*had sprang*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=nyp.33433044068959;view=1up;seq=136;skin=mobile) up in his heart was not the sudden, changeable fancy of a boy, but rather the wild, fierce passion of a man of strong will and imperious temper. — Arthur Conan Doyle, *A Study in Scarlet*, n.d., orig. 1887, 130.

This is not to say that those countless people on Yelp or Trip Advisor who write *was rang* lie in an unbroken tradition with Shakespeare and Conan Doyle, but such forms rarely appear out of nowhere and often continue a shadow existence in spoken dialect. It’s still English, just no longer considered standard because educated elites preferred other forms.

Comment: @KarlG Thanks for your intellectual and multi-dimensional response.

Comment: Haha! Let’s just call it an autocorrect typo :) . The +1 was mine.

Comment: The young lady is American and works at McDonalds: https://www.xlibris.com/Bookstore/BookDetail.aspx?BookId=SKU-001052323

Comment: The author Luck's book seems to have an Afro-American narrator and the author himself is Southern, by the looks of his Southern Fried life. https://www.amazon.com/David-Luck/e/B00SNWFKFW?ref=dbs_p_ebk_r00_abau_000000

Comment: A glance through Google hits shows that _was rang_ is not limited to any Southern dialect.

Answer (score 3):

> 1. So after dinner my cell phone **was rang** and it was Tom.
> 2. Ash was already in bed sleeping and didn't even move when the phone **was rang**.

There are many dialects in the English language that appear to mix the passive construction with the past continuous tense. One famous example is the British English  “**I was sat**” instead of the more standard construction “I was sitting”. Its use has become so widely spread that even [BBC reporters](https://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2012/10/03/continuous-tenses/) use this type of construction, e.g. **“we were stood at the bar waiting to be served”**

In the OP's case, in standard English, it should be **“my cell phone rang”** and the **“phone rang”**. It is the device that rings. If someone wanted to make the sentences passive they could write

- So after dinner, *a phone call* ***was made*** to tell me… (someone made a phone call.)
- *A call **was ignored/missed***  as Ash lay sleeping soundly. (Ash ignored/didn't hear the phone ring.)

Comment: But not unheard of for someone to say "He keeps ringing my phone (to see if I answer/to annoy me/to see if I am alright etc)."  or "He rang my phone three times yesterday".

Comment: I read through the entirety of your link to the Oxford Online dictionary and it says it says the usage is British regional and or Australian, New Zealand etc. I did not see anything about BBC reporters in it. In American English, it is simply regional or Afro-American. The two books are by a young lady who does not seem to be formally educated and the second book seems to have an Afro-American narrator.

Comment: @Lambie bad linking, but I assure you that some BBC reporters and British journalists use that construction. Halt! **perhaps I’m fighting a losing battle, given that this usage is now so widespread that the BBC and newspapers such as The Guardian implicitly appear to endorse it as well.**

Comment: I listen to the BBC "day and night". That said, it is my feeling that "to be sat" is used in lieu of "to be seated". If you google "be sat" at site:.uk, there is quite a bit of it. Check out this official site: The impact on passengers with reduced mobility, ***some of whom may have paid to be sat together*** with a carer when the airline would have sat them together for free.https://www.caa.co.uk/Passengers/Before-you-fly/Making-a-booking/Airline-seating-allocations/

Comment: So, it would seem that UK English and others accepts to be sat, for to be seated (American English). In any event, a phone still rings now and rang yesterday, regardless. As you are English, you might now see that.

Answer (score 0):

No. "was" requires either a noun phrase or a subject complement. "rang" is a verb. "rung" is the past participle and can act as a subject complement, so "the phone was rung" would be grammatically correct, but not idiomatic. The normal phrasing would be just "the phone rang". If the phone rang for a long time, then "the phone was ringing" might be appropriate.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Not when narrators are unschooled.

Comment: Past participles are typically categorized as verbs. So "rang" is a verb, and "rung" is also a verb (they are different forms of the same verb).

Comment: @sumelic Past participles act as adjectives and can follow linking verbs as subject complements. Finite verb forms cannot.

Answer (score 0):

A phone rings. Grammatically speaking, it is usually something the phone does, rather than something that is done to it. So it is not normally idiomatic to say "My phone was rang." (In any event, if it were the case it would need to be "was rung")

However, there are circumstances, where one is needing to emphasise the fact of the ringing, that one would say "He rang my phone". Usually it is where there has been a problem of some kind in making contact.

The different circumstances in which one might say "My phone rang", and "He rang my phone" may be a difficult nuance to grasp for a beginner. But for the latter to be used one usually needs to know the identity of the person ringing.

Comment: I wonder how all these smart people fall into these traps. Context is everything.

Comment: @Lambie It may be a regional dialect.